# How can I store custom RGB values in an ENUM or class

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to store custom colours for a simple game I'm working on.

**Example for Colours(RGB):**

(52, 73, 94)

(44, 62, 80)

I have tried creating an **ENUM** that would store them like this:

```
public enum Colours {
    WET_ASPHALT(52, 73, 94), MIDNIGHT_BLUE(44, 62, 80);
}
```

Though I'm not even sure if I did that right. I have tried searching this up and I found this:

```
public enum Colours {

WET_ASPHALT(52, 73, 94), MIDNIGHT_BLUE(44, 62, 80);

private final int r, g, b;
private final String rgb;

private Colours(final int r, final int g, final int b) {
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.rgb = r + ", " + g + ", " + b;
}

public String getRGB() {
    return rgb;
}

// You can add methods like this too
public int getRed() {
    return r;
}

public int getGreen() {
    return g;
}

public int getBlue() {
    return b;
}

}
```

Though I didn't understand the point of using `String` so I tried `Color` since I'd be using `g2d.setColor();` and it made sense to me, but that didn't work either.

I could simply create a `Colours` class and make each colour `static` but I'm told to stay away from static variables.

I could also be doing this right but I'm just not accessing the stored colours right.

Comment: Anything wrong with using something `java.awt.Color` (or any number of color classes) and `static final`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well I have in the past used `java.awt.Color` and I just made a simple `static final Color`, but isn't it proper to not use static?

Comment: `static final` is the main means for creating constants, `static` will allow people to change it, which isn't what you want to do. You could also create a `enum` of `Color`, instead of storing the RGB or create a method which returns the `Color` (instead of `String`), but it will all come down to your needs

Comment: There is nothing wrong to use constants (`static final`) if you need them as constants as well as nothing wrong to use just `static` when needed. Do not make things more complex than needed... Purpose of ENUM is just to restrict allowed values. Do you really need it?

Comment: Alright I'll just make a `Colours` class with `static finals`. Thanks for the help. I thought I was over-thinking it and I guess I was.

Comment: Stop using the term "constant" as a synonym for `static final`. It isn't.